# Como paso código de JavaScript a React JS usando Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Este código es un script para darle funcionamiento a un Sidebar, poder ocultarlo, cambiar la pantalla a modo oscuro y añadir funciones a los items que este contiene, el script está hecho en JavaScript, y por motivos laborales requiero pasarlo a React usando hooks como useState() y useEffect(). Si alguien pudiese echarme una mano estaría muy agradecido.

**Este es el código en Js:**

```
<script>
      const body = document.querySelector('body'),
        sidebar = body.querySelector('nav'),
        toggle = body.querySelector('.toggle'),
        searchBtn = body.querySelector('.search-box'),
        modeSwitch = body.querySelector('.toggle-switch'),
        modeText = body.querySelector('.mode-text');

      toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
        sidebar.classList.toggle('close');
      });

      searchBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        sidebar.classList.remove('close');
      });

      modeSwitch.addEventListener('click', () => {
        body.classList.toggle('dark');

        if (body.classList.contains('dark')) {
          modeText.innerText = 'Light mode';
        } else {
          modeText.innerText = 'Dark mode';
        }
      });
</script>
```

**Y este es el componente SideBar usando React:**

```
function Sidebar() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <nav className="sidebar close">
      <header>
        <i className="bx bx-chevron-right toggle"></i>
      </header>

      <div class="menu-bar">
        <div class="menu">
          <ul>
            <li class="search-box">
              <i class="bx bx-search icon"></i>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="bottom-content">
          <ul>
            <li class="mode">
              <div class="sun-moon">
                <i class="bx bx-moon icon moon"></i>
                <i class="bx bx-sun icon sun"></i>
              </div>
              <span class="mode-text text">Dark mode</span>

              <div class="toggle-switch">
                <span class="switch"></span>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}

export default Sidebar;
```

Answer (score 2):

Tu HTML tal y como está ahora tiene clases estáticas que son strings.

Pero puedes hacerlas dinámicas pasándoles a cada atributo `className` un operador ternario dentro que determine si se mostrará una clase u otra.

Algo así:

```
 return (
    <nav className={close ? "sidebar close" : "sidebar"}> ...
```

El operador ternario evaluará el estado `close` que será `true` o `false` dependiendo de las funciones que crees para setear dicho estado.

Por ejemplo:

```
 const [close, setClose] = useState(false);
 
 ...
 
 <li class="search-box" onClick={() => setClose(true)}>
```

Te dejo una pregunta que tiene otro ejemplo más de lo que digo:

[React conditional style on custom click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57532122/react-conditional-style-on-custom-click)